# Visual C# - Class methods?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I've been learning Visual C# 2010 for a day now. I've had about a year of experience with objective-c/xcode. In obj-c there are Class methods and Instance methods. I've figured out how to do instance methods in C# but how do you run (and make) a class method? The closest i have so far is this:

```
new Mode().selectScenario();
//and further below...
class Mode
{
    public string selectScenario()
    {
        return "select scenario";
    }

    public string enterToFind()
    {
        return "enter to find";
    }
}
```

What i am trying to do here is return a string when i do Mode.selectScenario() or something. In objective-c I would use `[Mode selectScenario]` but I'm not sure about C#.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Mode
{
    public static string selectScenario()
    {
        return "select scenario";
    }
}
```

Make the method method static by using the `static` modifier.

Static members belong to the type as opposed to the object instance.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick answer!. Works! Can't tick it for 13 mins though

Answer (score 0):

Make your method `selectScenario` `static`.

In that case you can call it without creating Mode instance like this

```
class Mode
{
    public static string selectScenario()
    {
        return "select scenario";
    }

    public static string enterToFind()
    {
        return "enter to find";
    }
}

string result = Mode.selectScenario();
```